# using form_for with a singular model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have a `Wizard` model that the client references w/o an ID (it's saved in the session), so I've created a singular resource for :show and :update.  I want the admin to have access to all instances of that model via index so admin can delete strays, so I've added a plural resources for :index and :destroy.  The index and destroy works, but I can't figure out the right arguments to pass to form_for in the update view.

### The setup

```
# config/routes.rb
WTest::Application.routes.draw.do
  resource :wizard, :only => [:show, :update]
  resources :wizards, :only => [:index, :destroy]
  ...
end
```

resulting in

```
$ rake routes
wizards GET    /wizards(.:format)     {:action=>"index", :controller=>"wizards"}
 wizard DELETE /wizards/:id(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"wizards"}
        GET    /wizard(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"wizards"}
        PUT    /wizard(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"wizards"}
```

This sets up routes the way I'd expect.

### The question (revised since original post)

In the console:

```
>> app.wizard_path
```

raises the error `ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"wizards"}`

Why is this?  Have I set up my routes incorrectly?  I need to specify `:url => wizard_path` for form_for() in the wizards's update view.

### The details

If I specify an explicit path in my call to form_for:

```
# app/view/wizards/update.html.erb
<%= form_for @wizard, :url => wizard_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

... then attempting to render this for gets an error on the form_for line:

```
No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"wizards"}
```

I have no idea why it's trying to match the destroy action.  How do I get the form to submit to the `{action=>"update", :controller=>"wizards"}` route?

(By the way, I looked at [bug 267](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/267), and I don't think it is the same as what I'm observing.  But if it is this bug, is there a workaround?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carrying on the long tradition of answering my own questions (meh!), I think I figured it out.  If my analysis is wrong, I'd be happy to give someone else the checkmark...

### The cause of the problem

Look at the output of `rake routes`

```
$ rake routes
wizards GET    /wizards(.:format)     {:action=>"index", :controller=>"wizards"}
 wizard DELETE /wizards/:id(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"wizards"}
        GET    /wizard(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"wizards"}
        PUT    /wizard(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"wizards"}
```

The path method 'wizard_path' is ambiguous: it can either refer to the DELETE clause, in which case it needs an :id argument (`wizard_path(22)`), or it can refer to the GET and PUT clauses, in which case it doesn't take an ID argument.

### The solution

So my solution was to create a route specifically for deletion.  My revised `routes.rb` file now reads:

```
resources :wizards, :only => [:index]
resource :wizard, :only => [:show, :update]
match 'wizard/:id' => 'wizards#destroy', :via => :delete, :as => :delete_wizard
```

and `rake routes` now produces:

```
$ rake routes
      wizards GET    /wizards(.:format)    {:action=>"index", :controller=>"wizards"}
       wizard GET    /wizard(.:format)     {:action=>"show", :controller=>"wizards"}
              PUT    /wizard(.:format)     {:action=>"update", :controller=>"wizards"}
delete_wizard DELETE /wizard/:id(.:format) {:controller=>"wizards", :action=>"destroy"}
```

I needed to make a one-line change to the delete link in wizards/index.html.erb to use the new delete_wizard_path, but everything works now.